# Linq Lambda get two properties as string from aggretation

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, aggregate, anonymous-class

Inside a linq query to an anonymous select I want to concatenate strings from two properties.

For instance to find the full name of the oldest person in some grouping of persons.

```
var personsAndOldest = db.Persons.GroupBy(person => person.SomeThingThatCanBeGroupedForPerson).Select(a => new
            {
                FirstName = a.FirstOrDefault().FirstName,
                LastName = a.FirstOrDefault().LastName,
                BirthDate = a.FirstOrDefault().BirthDate,
                FullnameOfOldes = a.Aggregate((pers1, pers2) => pers1.BirthDate > pers2.BirthDate ? pers1 : pers2).FirstName + " " //How do I get LastName of the old one (without using the full aggregate again)
            });
```

Do I have to write the full aggregation again to get the LastName after the firstname and whitespace?

Comment: Do you want every result to have the full name of the oldest person, or do you want only the oldest person to have `FullnameOfOldes` populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lambda statement in the Select:

```
var personsAndOldest = db.Persons.GroupBy(person => person.SomeThingThatCanBeGroupedForPerson).Select(a => 
    {
        var first = a.First();
        var oldest = a.Aggregate((pers1, pers2) => pers1.BirthDate > pers2.BirthDate ? pers1 : pers2);
        return new
        {
            FirstName = first.FirstName,
            LastName = first.LastName,
            BirthDate = first.BirthDate,
            FullnameOfOldes = oldest.FirstName + " " + oldest.LastName)
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as

```
var personsAndOldest = db.Persons
    .GroupBy(person => person.SomeThingThatCanBeGroupedForPerson)
    .Select(g => new 
        {
            a = g.First(),
            o = g.Aggregate((pers1, pers2) =>
                pers1.BirthDate > pers2.BirthDate ? pers1 : pers2)
        })
    .Select(pair => new
        {
            FirstName = pair.a.FirstName,
            LastName = pair.a.LastName,
            BirthDate = pair.a.BirthDate,
            FullnameOfOldes = pair.o.FirstName + " " + pair.o.LastName
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `let` to introduce new range variables.
- You don't need to specify property name for anonymous type if it equals name of assigned property
- I think `OrderBy` will find oldest person (but you can use aggregate and compare performance)
- I believe that oldest person is one with minimal birth date, so you need to change aggregation to `pers1.BirthDate < pers2.BirthDate ? pers1 : pers2`

So

```
var personsAndOldest = from p in db.Persons
                       group p by p.SomeThingThatCanBeGroupedForPerson into g
                       let first = g.FirtOrDefault()
                       let oldest = g.OrderBy(x => x.BirthDate).FirstOrefault()
                       select
                       {
                           first.FirstName,
                           first.LastName,
                           first.BirthDate,
                           FullnameOfOldes = oldest.FirstName + " " + oldest.LastName
                       };
```

Comment: Huh, I'd not thought about it until I read your third bullet, but this use of `Aggregate` looks like a viable alternative to MoreLINQ's `MaxBy` or the `O(n log n)` `OrderBy(...).First()`.

Comment: @Rawling thanks a lot for mentioning `morelinq`! It's very interesting to take a look on their implementations